# nRF51822 bricked after faulty boot loader

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, firmware, cortex-m0

I have a custom board (a chinese game pad) which uses a chip named n51802, which according to nordic is a “custom” nrf51822 - completely compatible with it though.

I “accidentally” (fiddling around) flashed an image that came with the nRF Toolbox for iOS and i think i corrupted the bootloader.

The device does not respond (it has two LEDs, which stay off, but i don’t know exactly to which pins are they connected to) and no bluetooth is discovered (check with various devices - iOS, android, linux).

I found out that i can force DFU mode by pulling `P0.20` low, though it is very difficult (almost impossible) to solder a wire on the chip itself, and it’s not used at all at the pcb.

The only possible solution is to use JTAG flashing, but i’m not sure if it will work and i currently don’t have the required tools to carry out the operation (will test it soon though).

Is there any other way i can save the day and flash it OTA?

Comment: Over-the-air updates require the bootloader, so pretty much by definition, if you've corrupted the bootloader, then that approach -- or any other approach using "ordinary" I/O -- isn't going to work. As you say, the only possible solution is to use JTAG. I'm not sure why you would think otherwise.

Comment: cause it’s rather difficult to corrupt the bootloader. i’m not sure if i’ve corrupted the bootloader or later parts of the firmware. i have no way to check that though.